# How can I find the upper and lower boundary for quick sort?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I got the average case complexity for quick sort.Now how can I find the upper and lower bounds for quick sort?

Comment: In a good book about algorithms maybe?

Comment: Think of cases that are easy or hard for quick sort and determine their running times. Hint: nicely balanced and heavily unbalanced.

Comment: (There are trivial bounds, and there are tight bounds. In a single thread, _space complexity_ can not exceed _time complexity_, but what about _power_, _ease of adaptation_ or _ease of maintenance_?) Can a _sort_ be correct if it ignores even a single value? Look at the _partition_ step: what is the largest partition that might get created?

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of the Quick Sort is O(N log(N)) with a worst case of O(N^2).  This is due to the fact that it must go through all the numbers of the array and divide them equally. into two sub arrays that are lower and higher then the selected pivot. Each of these sub arrays must continue through the same process. This divide and conquer continues until there are only arrays of size 2 that are sorted correctly.  To compute this it takes N log(N).  this is easily seen with a binary tree, where the leaves (the bottom rows) are sorted.  Then you just concatenate them.

```
      8
  4       4
2   2   2   2
```

Quick Sort runs into problems when you have a sorted array.  Something like insertion sort would have a O(N) time algorithm at this situation.  Dealing with arrays that are partially sorted and you need a time crunch (that is if you are dealing with Millions of Data), then you might want to create a algorithm of your own design that suits your taste.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: "The time complexity of the Quick Sort is always O(N log(N))." - your reference says otherwise.